# Regex for rectangle brackets in R

Tags: regex, r

Conventionally in R one can use metacharacters in a regex with two slashes, e.g. ( becomes \(, but I find the same isn't true for square brackets.

```
mystring <- "abc[de"

#remove [,] and $ characters

gsub("[\\[\\]$]","",mystring)

[1] "abc[de"
```

`[[:punct:]]` works but I hate to use a non-standard regex if I don't have to. Can the regex set syntax be used?

Comment: Why not `gsub("(\\[|\\]|\\$)","",mystring)`? Still standard regex, right?

Comment: @Frank: That works for me. If you wanted, you could add `|\\$` for completeness with the OP's example. Regardless, post that as an answer and you've got yourself an upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should enable `perl = TRUE`, then you can use Perl-like syntax which is more straight-forward (IMHO):

```
gsub("[\\[\\]$]","",mystring, perl = TRUE)
```

Or, you may use "smart placement" when placing `]` at the start of the bracket expression (`[` is not special inside it, there is no need escaping `[` there):

```
gsub("[][$]","",mystring)
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/61DxFF)

Result:

```
[1] "abcde"
```

**More details**

The `[...]` construct is considered a [*bracket expression*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) by the TRE regex  engine (used by default in base R regex functions - (g)sub, grep(l), (g)regexpr -  when used without `perl=TRUE`), which is a POSIX regex construct. Bracket expressions, unlike [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in NFA regex engines, do not support *escape sequences*, i.e. the `\` char is treated as a a literal backslash char inside them.

Thus, the `[\[\]]` in a TRE regex matches `\` or `[` char (with the `[\[\]` part that is actually equal to `[\[]`) and then a `]`. So, it matches `\]` or `[]` substrings, just have a look at `gsub("[\\[\\]]", "", "[]\\]ab]")` [demo](https://rextester.com/MOEEZ57873) - it outputs `ab]` because `[]` and `\]` are matched and eventually removed.

Note that the terms *POSIX bracket expressions* and *NFA character classes* are used in the same meaning as is used at https://www.regular-expressions.info, it is not quite a standard, but there is a need to differentiate between the two.

Comment: The default in the R regex functions should really be `perl = TRUE`.

Answer (score 4):

I would sidestep `[ab]` syntax and use `(a|b)`. Besides working, it may also be more readable:

```
gsub("(\\[|\\]|\\$)","",mystring)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `\\[` as the thing to match, you don't need additional square brackets unless you are matching multiple options:

```
> mystring <- 'abc[de'
> gsub("\\[", "", mystring)
[1] "abcde"
```

You can make this even simpler and faster for single characters by taking away the special meaning using `fixed=TRUE`:

```
> mystring <- 'abc[de'
> gsub("[", "", mystring, fixed=TRUE)
[1] "abcde"
```

Or if the first thing inside of square brackets is square brackets (unescaped), then they are taken as the literal character rather than having the usual special meaning:

```
> mystring <- 'a,bc[d]e$'
> gsub("[][,$]", "", mystring)
[1] "abcde"
```

Comment: Oh, that last point is interesting. Including the comma might just be confusing (since the other three chars -- `][$` -- are actually in the OP), though.